# In my Python CGI script, how do I save to disk a file uploaded via POST request of data entered by the user in a form?

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi

The client has a simple form that takes a text and a file:

```
<form name="add_show" id="add_show" action="" method="GET">

    <label class="text-info">Show Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="show_name" name="show_name" placeholder="My Show Name" required><br><br>

    <label class="text-info">Show's File (JSON):</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required><br><br>

    <p><input class="btn btn-danger btn-small" name="button2" value="Add the Show!" onClick="addFullShow(this.form)"></p>

</form>
```

With Javascript I send the data to the server's Python CGI script:

```
function addFullShow(form) {

      alert("about to send form");

      var formElement = form;
      formData = new FormData(formElement);

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "myScript.cgi");
      xhr.send(formData);

    }
```

And in the server side Python CGI script I have the field storage `fs = cgi.FieldStorage()`, and I know how to get the text values, i.e. `fs['key'].value`.

How do I save the file uploaded to disk?

I hope I'm clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this code to store the file on disk

```
import os, cgi
fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem = fs['userfile']

# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:
   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
   open('/tmp/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
   message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
else:
   message = 'No file was uploaded'
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. Just an addition to anyone reading this, must also import os.path & cgi.