# Using XHR to update a server file and add option to html select

Tags: javascript, python, html, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to have the input field add text into a file that is on the server and add it to the select element on the webpage dynamically but it is not working out so well. Currently I am getting an error that e1 is null and the text is not getting appended to my testdoc.txt text file. If I take out the code to try and write to the text file this works without issue. I also tried without the dynamic adding to the select field to see if it would append to file and that does not go. In firebug I do see the post and I see a response but it does not get appended to the file. Below is a snippet of my current code.

```
function submitxhr(){
 var e1=document.getElementById('item');
 var e2=document.getElementById('items');
 var o=document.createElement('option');
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
 o.value=e1.value;
 o.text=e1.value;
 e2.options.add(o);
 xhr.open("POST","testdoc.txt");  
 xhr.send(e1);
};

 <form id="myForm"> 
   <input name="item" type="text" value="" />  
   <select size="3" id="items" name="items">
   <input type="button" value="submit"  ONCLICK="submitxhr()">   
 </form>
```

My next step is then to create a remove button for the options in the select form but I have not gotten there yet but any help would be much appreciated.

[UPDATE] If I am able to pass the XHR POST into a python CGI script I could figure out both adding and removing. Currently, I am unable to pass the POST into the python CGI script. It cannot find the e1 variable when passed.

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

value1 = form.getvalue[e1]

f = open(r'testdoc.txt', 'a')
f.write(e1)
f.close()
```

I even checked out this question but when I make a test script using this, I also get a null value, "message = 'writelines() requires an iterable argument'".
[In my Python CGI script, how do I save to disk a file uploaded via POST request of data entered by the user in a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947988/in-my-python-cgi-script-how-do-i-save-to-disk-a-file-uploaded-via-post-request)

It does look like the value is getting passed but maybe I am not pulling the data out correctly.
f = , f.writelines = , fileitem = FieldStorage('userfile', None, 'sghjsjh')

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten adding the `id` to the first `input` field! It should be:

```
<input id="item" name="item" type="text" value="" />
```

instead of

```
<input name="item" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks that did allow me to insert into my select form. I must of glazed for it after working on this all day yesterday. I just need to append to my text file now. I tried using python to get the post since my original backend script is python but it doesnt seem to get the e1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone that comes by to see this and wants to know the answer after playing around for a few hours I finally was able to update my text file though a python CGI script and thanks to kol he got it so I could input an option into my select field as I totally missed a key field.

I needed to update my original webpage to the following:

```
function submitxhr(form){
 var e1=document.getElementById('item');
 var e2=document.getElementById('items');
 var o=document.createElement('option');
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
 o.value=e1.value;
 o.text=e1.value;
 e2.options.add(o);
 var formElement = form;
 formData = new FormData(formElement);
 xhr.open("POST","appendtest3.cgi");
 xhr.send(formData);
};

 <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="POST">  
 <input id="item" name="item" type="text" value="" />
 <select size="3" id="items" name="items">
 <input type="button" value="submit"  ONCLICK="submitxhr(this.form)">
 </form>
```

And added this as my python CGI script to pass the input field into my text file.

```
fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
payload = fs.getvalue('item', 'unknown')

f = open(r'testdoc.txt', 'a')
f.writelines(payload + "\n")
f.close()
```

This worked for what I needed it to do. I am sure there is a better way of doing it but this is what I have for now.